# How to show Google Map on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5

I apologize for the newbie question. I'm trying to display a very basic google map on my show.html.erb; but for some reason nothing is being displayed. However, in a seperate part my app - different controller and view - a map is able to be generated. I've listed my relevant code below, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="map2"> #I have also tried it with just
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**farms_controller.rb**

```
class FarmsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]

  def show
    @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def set_farm
    @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def farm_params
    params.require(:farm).permit(:name, :farm_id, :avatar, :background)
  end
end
```

**farmsController.js**

```
FarmsController = {
  initialize: function() {
    this.createMap();
    this.getLocationOnSelect();
  },
  markers: [],
  map: null,    
  createMap: function(){                                    
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'),{
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.751,-73.99),
              zoom: 11,
              mapTypeControl: false           
    });
  },
}

function initMap(){
  FarmsController.initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find the issue and resolve it, my javascript Google Maps API in my application layout file had at the end of it a `callback=InitMap` which worked perfect for the separate part of my application. However, because now I was using InitMap in my farmsController.js file as well **two places instead of only one** - it would not work there too.

To solve this what was needed were the following step process:

Change in my **application.html.erb**

Remove my Google maps Api key

At the end of the file, right after `<%= yield %>` put down `<%= yield :gmaps %>`

Go to **farmsController.js** and change `function initMap` to `farmsInitMap`

Go to my show.html.erb for farms and input the following code

`<%= content_for :gmaps do %><script async defer src="GoogleMapsAPIcallback=farmsInitMap">
</script>
<% end %>`

Go to your other part of your application and do a similar process changing `function initMap` and making sure to post the Google Maps rails content code in that relevant map show html page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `initMap()` from a javascript block in your `show.html.erb`?

```
<script>
initMap();
</script>
```

Google has some documentation on how to add a map to your document: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Also, as side note... you don't need to whitelist the `:farm_id` parameter in `FarmsController#farm_params`. The `:id` is passed in the params and should be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Gmaps4Rails` https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails
It is developed to simply create a Google Map with overlays.